# Find All paths in a Directed Cyclic Graph

Tags: graph, networkx, path-finding

Actually I am working on a text based **Directed** Graph having each word as a node in the graph and edges are between 2 adjacent words in a sentence of the text.

I need to find all the paths from a **START** node to **END** node.

Is there any library for **Python** which can help me with the task?

I actually tried doing it with **networkx**, but problem with networkx is that it outputs only simple paths (Simple paths are pretty short for a long sentence in input and don't contain much information of the sentence). And I need more complex paths for my task.

Comment: Try looking for tree traversal algorithms, they will do the trick. i.e. http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Trees/TreeTraversals.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the algorithm for `DFS`(depth first search) or `BFS`(Breadth first search) to collect all paths. below is the example to collect all possible paths from `source` to `destination` written in java.

```
    package com.nirav.modi;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
    import java.util.Set;

    class Graph<T> implements Iterable<T> {

        /*
         * A map from nodes in the graph to sets of outgoing edges. Each set of
         * edges is represented by a map from edges to doubles.
         */
        private final Map<T, Map<T, Double>> graph = new HashMap<T, Map<T, Double>>();

        /**
         * Adds a new node to the graph. If the node already exists then its a
         * no-op.
         * 
         * @param node
         *            Adds to a graph. If node is null then this is a no-op.
         * @return true if node is added, false otherwise.
         */
        public boolean addNode(T node) {
            if (node == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("The input node cannot be null.");
            }
            if (graph.containsKey(node))
                return false;

            graph.put(node, new HashMap<T, Double>());
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Given the source and destination node it would add an arc from source to
         * destination node. If an arc already exists then the value would be
         * updated the new value.
         * 
         * @param source
         *            the source node.
         * @param destination
         *            the destination node.
         * @param length
         *            if length if
         * @throws NullPointerException
         *             if source or destination is null.
         * @throws NoSuchElementException
         *             if either source of destination does not exists.
         */
        public void addEdge(T source, T destination, double length) {
            if (source == null || destination == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Source and Destination, both should be non-null.");
            }
            if (!graph.containsKey(source) || !graph.containsKey(destination)) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Source and Destination, both should be part of graph");
            }
            /* A node would always be added so no point returning true or false */
            graph.get(source).put(destination, length);
        }

        /**
         * Removes an edge from the graph.
         * 
         * @param source
         *            If the source node.
         * @param destination
         *            If the destination node.
         * @throws NullPointerException
         *             if either source or destination specified is null
         * @throws NoSuchElementException
         *             if graph does not contain either source or destination
         */
        public void removeEdge(T source, T destination) {
            if (source == null || destination == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Source and Destination, both should be non-null.");
            }
            if (!graph.containsKey(source) || !graph.containsKey(destination)) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Source and Destination, both should be part of graph");
            }
            graph.get(source).remove(destination);
        }

        /**
         * Given a node, returns the edges going outward that node, as an immutable
         * map.
         * 
         * @param node
         *            The node whose edges should be queried.
         * @return An immutable view of the edges leaving that node.
         * @throws NullPointerException
         *             If input node is null.
         * @throws NoSuchElementException
         *             If node is not in graph.
         */
        public Map<T, Double> edgesFrom(T node) {
            if (node == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("The node should not be null.");
            }
            Map<T, Double> edges = graph.get(node);
            if (edges == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Source node does not exist.");
            }
            return Collections.unmodifiableMap(edges);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the iterator that travels the nodes of a graph.
         * 
         * @return an iterator that travels the nodes of a graph.
         */
        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return graph.keySet().iterator();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Given a connected directed graph, find all paths between any two input
     * points.
     */
    public class GraphTester<T> {

        private final Graph<T> graph;

        /**
         * Takes in a graph. This graph should not be changed by the client
         */
        public GraphTester(Graph<T> graph) {
            if (graph == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("The input graph cannot be null.");
            }
            this.graph = graph;
        }

        private void validate(T source, T destination) {

            if (source == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("The source: " + source + " cannot be  null.");
            }
            if (destination == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("The destination: " + destination + " cannot be  null.");
            }
            if (source.equals(destination)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The source and destination: " + source + " cannot be the same.");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns the list of paths, where path itself is a list of nodes.
         * 
         * @param source
         *            the source node
         * @param destination
         *            the destination node
         * @return List of all paths
         */
        public List<List<T>> getAllPaths(T source, T destination) {
            validate(source, destination);

            List<List<T>> paths = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
            recursive(source, destination, paths, new LinkedHashSet<T>());
            return paths;
        }

        // so far this dude ignore's cycles.
        private void recursive(T current, T destination, List<List<T>> paths, LinkedHashSet<T> path) {
            path.add(current);

            if (current == destination) {
                paths.add(new ArrayList<T>(path));
                path.remove(current);
                return;
            }

            final Set<T> edges = graph.edgesFrom(current).keySet();

            for (T t : edges) {
                if (!path.contains(t)) {
                    recursive(t, destination, paths, path);
                }
            }

            path.remove(current);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Graph<String> graphFindAllPaths = new Graph<String>();
            graphFindAllPaths.addNode("A");
            graphFindAllPaths.addNode("B");
            graphFindAllPaths.addNode("C");
            graphFindAllPaths.addNode("D");

            graphFindAllPaths.addEdge("A", "B", 10);
            graphFindAllPaths.addEdge("A", "C", 10);
            graphFindAllPaths.addEdge("B", "D", 10);
            graphFindAllPaths.addEdge("C", "D", 10);

            graphFindAllPaths.addEdge("B", "C", 10);
            graphFindAllPaths.addEdge("C", "B", 10);

            GraphTester<String> findAllPaths = new GraphTester<String>(graphFindAllPaths);
            List<List<String>> allPaths = findAllPaths.getAllPaths("A", "D");
            System.out.println(allPaths);

            // assertEquals(paths, findAllPaths.getAllPaths("A", "D"));
        }
    }
```